# SQL Найти и заменить часть текста с тегами

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В базе данных, в поле description есть фрагмент кода:

```
&lt;video id=&quot;58e482246c5fb6426489b990b1057fe1&quot; class=&quot;video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-youtube&quot; controls preload=&quot;auto&quot; width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; poster=&quot;%3Cimg+src%3D%22%2Fimages%2Fproduct%2F200x150%2F60713.jpg%22+alt%3D%22%22+width%3D%22200%22+height%3D%22150%22+%2F%3E&quot; data-setup='{&quot;techOrder&quot;:[&quot;youtube&quot;],&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLL9ZuaZ_kY&quot;}'&gt;&lt;/video&gt;
```

или для наглядности:

```
<video id="58e482246c5fb6426489b990b1057fe1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-youtube" controls="" preload="auto" width="560" height="315" poster="%3Cimg+src%3D%22%2Fimages%2Fproduct%2F200x150%2F44684.jpg%22+alt%3D%22%22+width%3D%22200%22+height%3D%22150%22+%2F%3E" data-setup="{&quot;techOrder&quot;:[&quot;youtube&quot;],&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63PkeC4Rl5k&amp;feature=youtu.be&quot;}"></video>
```

Можно ли с помощью SQL запроса убрать всё лишнее, оставить только ссылку и обернуть её в другой тэг? Чтобы получилось что-то вроде:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/63PkeC4Rl5k" width="640" height="360" class="note-video-clip"></iframe>
```

Обращаю внимания на то, что просто убрать все тэги не вариант, по-мимо этого фрагмента, есть ещё много чего другого.

Comment: А почему бы не сделать это регулярными выражениями на php?

Comment: Потому-что интересно как это можно было бы сделать через SQL, база очень большая, порядка 30 тысяч записей. В регулярках я не разбираюсь, поэтому если подскажите как сделать, буду благодарен

Comment: разве нельзя добавить ещё колонку с форматом строки который вам нужен, тогда осталось перевести вашу изначальную строку в ту которую вам нужно средствами php, через парсинг селекторов думаю можно привести к нужному виду или регуляркой

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh а если записей 1кк, то тоже через php делать? Мне кажется вы по скорости просядите...

Comment: вам лучше пересмотреть структуру БД...если вы так храните данные, то структура уже не верна

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц на крайний случай сделать запрос insert select, который перегонит всё в новый формат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что то типо **дампа**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`,`content`) VALUES
  ('1', '<video id="58e482246c5fb6426489b990b1057fe1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-youtube" controls="" preload="auto" width="560" height="315" poster="%3Cimg+src%3D%22%2Fimages%2Fproduct%2F200x150%2F44684.jpg%22+alt%3D%22%22+width%3D%22200%22+height%3D%22150%22+%2F%3E" data-setup="{&quot;techOrder&quot;:[&quot;youtube&quot;],&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63PkeC4Rl5k&amp;feature=youtu.be&quot;}"></video>')
```

ну и **выборка**

```
-- based on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/808921

SELECT a.id, CONCAT('<iframe frameborder="0" ',SUBSTRING(a.content, POSITION("src&quot;:&quot;" IN a.content),POSITION("}" IN a.content) - POSITION("src&quot;:&quot;" IN a.content)),' width="640" height="360" class="note-video-clip"></iframe>') as Ссылка
FROM `docs` a
```

**результат**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну и [ссылка](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e34f6f/37/0) на рабочий пример

**время выполнения**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**что нужно понимать для запроса**

[substring](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp) - вырезает из строки указанное кол-во символов с указанного индекса

[length](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_length.asp) - возвращает длину строки в байтах

[position](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_position.asp) - возвращает индекс найденного элемента в строке

[concat](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) - слияние строк

Ну и чутка **теории** вам:

*Первая нормальная форма* - Отношение находится в 1НФ, если все его атрибуты являются простыми, все используемые домены должны содержать только скалярные значения. Не должно быть повторений строк в таблице.

Взято [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/post/254773/) - это все к тому, что значение ссылки можно заносить в отдельный столбец в БД

Comment: интересный запрос, а если в таблице 30 тысяч записей, как автор написал какая будет скорость выполнения?

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh думаю скорее, чем на php

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать. Сразу вопрос, в теге <video id="58e482246c5fb6426489b990b1057fe1", айди в каждой записи разный, всё остальное (кроме ссылки) идентично, как это учесть?

Comment: @pon89aa но вы ж id отбрасываете...зачем учитывать?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц  походу голова уже не варит, но в вашем примере при дампе идёт конретный ид

Comment: @pon89aa ну это я для себя заполнил данные...у вас же свои есть )

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh я вставил скрин, на котором скорость видна